# Converting .pem to .key file

Tags: certificates, rsa, x.509, certificate-revocation

I downloaded certificated for my website using letsencrypt:

```
letsencrypt -d crackerscreed.me --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

The process was successful but the site I want to implement these certificates on is expecting `.key` file for private key. There are many solution which tells the solution using openSSL:

When I tried:

```
openssl rsa -outform der -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/crackerscreed.me/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/crackerscreed.me/privkey.key
```

The site popped an error saying:

> Invalid KEY format encountered. Your file doesn't seem a valid key!
>   Please, upload valid key file.

and when I tried with x509 instead of RSA,

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in /etc/letsencrypt/live/crackerscreed.me/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/crackerscreed.me/privkey.key
unable to load certificate
```

OpenSSL popped an error saying:

> unable to load certificate 140343522624768:error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start
>   line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:691:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

What do I do now? Is there a way to properly convert the file? If not, can I revoke these certificates and create new ones and somehow ask `letsencrypt` to provide me certificates directly as `.key` file instead of `.pem` file?

Comment: `openssl x509` is for a certificate, not a key. `openssl rsa` produces a raw PKCS1 RSAPrivateKey; are you sure your site wants that? I don't know any sw besides OpenSSL that supports it, and OpenSSL sw usually uses PEM not DER. There is no standard for what a `.key` file is but one of the two forms of PKCS8, or possibly PKCS12, seems much more likely; Microsoft PVK is also possible. Find out what your site wants -- exactly.

Comment: The extension of the file by itself is meaningless. What does the content looks like, at least its beginning?